# What can I do to get rid of the 'int' object is not subscriptable error in my main function def model:

Tags: python

I am doing my GCSE this summer and am confused as to why this line of code will not be accepted.
Any help will be helpful.

Error is coming from line `print('First gen \nJuveniles in gen 1',new_gens[0][0],'\nAdults in gen 1',new_gens[0][1],'\nSeniles in gen 1',new_gens[0][2])`

I am trying to make a first generation of greenflies, however I am struggling to even get them printed and python is saying that the integer is not subscriptable.

```
def Menu():
    again = True
    while again == True:
        print('\n------------------GreenFly Model------------------\n\n')
        print('MENU\n')

        print('Option 1\t Set the Generation 0 values')
        print('Option 2\t Display the Generation 0 values')
        print('Option 3\t Run the model')
        print('Option 4\t Quit')
        print('Select an option from above')
        choice = str(input('What is your option?'))
        if choice == '1':
            Generation_0()
        elif choice == '2':
            Display_Generation_0()
        elif choice == '3':
            model()
        elif choice == '4':    
            quit_model()
            again = False
        else:
            print('invalid option, Try again') 

def Generation_0():
    global gen0
    Juveniles = int(input('How many Juveniles? '))
    Adults = int(input('How many Adults? '))
    Seniles = int(input('How many Sentiles? '))
    BR = int(input('What is your birthrate? ')) 
    J_Survrate = int(input('Juvenile survival rate between 0&1'))
    A_Survrate = int(input('Adult survival rate between 0&1'))
    S_Survrate = int(input('Senile survival rate between 0&1'))
    num_gen=int(input('Birth rate between 5 and 25'))
    gen0 = [[Juveniles,Adults,Seniles], #stores all the information in a 2d array
            [BR],
            [J_Survrate,A_Survrate,S_Survrate],
            [num_gen]]
    gens.append(gen0)
    print(gen0)
    Menu()


def Display_Generation_0(): #lists out the 2d array
    print('Generation 0\nJuvenile numbers are ',gen0[0][0], "\nAdult numbers are ",gen0[0][1],'\nSenile numbers are ',gen0[0][2],'\nBirth rate is ',gen0[1][0],'\nJunior survival rate is ',gen0[2][0], '\nAdult survival rate is ',gen0[2][1], '\nSenile survival rate is ',gen0[2][2], '\nNumber of generations is ',gen0[3][0],)    


def model():
    new_gens = [(gen0[0][1]*gen0[1][0]),(gen0[0][0]*gen0[2][0]),((gen0[0][1]*gen0[2][1])+(gen0[0][2]*gen0[2][2]))]
    print('First gen \nJuveniles in gen 1',new_gens[0][0],'\nAdults in gen 1',new_gens[0][1],'\nSeniles in gen 1',new_gens[0][2])

#Main
gens=[]
Menu()
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of your error

Comment: Chances are, you are trying to slice a variable which contains an `int` value, subscript methods can also be used on strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new_gens is a 1 dimensional array, you are indexing into it as if its a 2D array. You are trying to index into a number which won't work. For clarity, new_gens is actually something like this:

```
new_gens = [122, 35, 88]
```

What `new_gens[0][0]` is saying is get the *1st element* in the new_gens array and then get the *1st element* of whatever was in that bucket. You can see that 122 is just a number and not another list.

You can get the index you want by simply indexing like this:

```
    JUVENILES_INDEX, ADULTS_INDEX, SENILES_INDEX = 0, 1, 2

    print('First gen \nJuveniles in gen 1',new_gens[JUVENILES_INDEX],'\nAdults in gen 1',new_gens[ADULTS_INDEX],'\nSeniles in gen 1',new_gens[SENILES_INDEX])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `new_gens` is really an array of 3 data.

So when you do `new_gens[0][0]` it's like doing (int(1))[0] you will get

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So should do something like:

```
print("First gen \nJuveniles in gen 1",new_gens[0],"\nAdults in gen 1",new_gens[1],"\nSeniles in gen 1",new_gens[2])
```